# How to define standard port numbers for different apps

Tags: deployment, weblogic, port

We have several enterprise application to deploy on Weblogic server.
 As you know for each domain we could define specific port, deploy an application on that and clients could access to server application by that port.
 My question is about the port number standard.
Is there any standard to assign server ports number to different application, if No what is your suggestion ? Is counting method (for example) god ?!! or ...

Thanks for your replies

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy your applications in different managed servers. What you have to do is create a managed server per application under your weblogic domain. During the configuration of the managed server you will be asked to give a port number. After setting the managed server your applications can be deployed on them, using the ports you have specified earlier. More information about the weblogic managed servers can be found in weblogic administration guide.